# Template that calls member function on argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have some code that creates several listeners. Thus I was thinking about adding a template that calls the notify on different types of listeners. However I am not sure how to call the member function (which all have different arguments) in a template. I am using C++17.

```
template <class T>
void notifyListeners(std::vector<T*> listeners, std::function<???> memfunc)  {
  // perhaps add a compile time check to see if memfunc exists
  for (auto& listener : listeners) {
    listener->memfunc();
  }
}
```

For example I have two classes of listeners :

```
class IFooListener {
  void Foo(int, double, std::string);
}

class IBarListener {
  void Bar(std::string, std::string)
}

std::vector<IFooListeners*> fooListeners;
std::vector<IBarListeners*> barListeners;
```

I would like to be able to do something  like this:

```
notifyListeners(fooListeners, &IFooListener::Foo, 1, 2.0, "Bla");
notifyListeners(barListeners, &IBarListener::Bar, "one", "two");
```

How can this be done?

Comment: `member function (which all have different arguments)` I'm not sure that function template is a good choice here if you need different implementation for different classes

Comment: I'd use a lambda instead of fussing around with member function pointers and re-inventing `std::bind`: `notifyListeners(fooListeners, [](IFoo *listener) { listener->Foo(1, 2.0, "Bla"); })`, with `template<typename T, typename F> notifyListeners(vector<T>, F callback);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
template <class T, typename F, typename... Args>
void notifyListeners(std::vector<T*> listeners, F f, Args&&... args)  {
  for (auto& listener : listeners) {
    (listener->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EPTqc38vx)

Comment: `std::invoke(f, *listener, args...)` would also allow regular functor (such as lambda) for `F`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand problem correctly. Here is my first approach using C++17:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Notifier {
public:
    void addObserver(T observer)
    {
        mObservers.emplace_back(observer);
    }

    template<auto f, typename...Ts>
    void notify(Ts&&...args) const
    {
        for(auto& p : mObservers)
        {
            notifyOne<f>(p, std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
        }
    }

private:
    template<auto f, typename...Ts>
    static void notifyOne(T p, Ts&&...args)
    {
        (p->*f)(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> mObservers;
};
```

Here as [some tests proving it works](https://godbolt.org/z/7c5Wj6Y17).

**Disclaimer**: I used perfect forwarding, but in case same argument may be used multiple times this is not best choice. I think some protection form moving argument values should be added.

Here is [C++11 version](https://godbolt.org/z/K1fxWjsWr) with function pointer pass as function argument.

**Edit**: Got another improvement. Now this template is able to handle `std::weak_ptr`: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z8r8Pc71j)